# Mongo Java Driver creates three clients

Tags: java, mongodb, cdi

I'm creating a application scoped mongo client to reuse it in my app. The first time the mongo client is accessed I see the following log entires in my server log indicating three clients are created. The third client is the one that is created in application scope as you can see by the preceding info message.
I can additionally see in the mongodb logs that 2 additional connections are opened and not closed or reused by succeeding calls.

```
[08.09.14 20:09:57:060 CEST] 000000c9 Mongo         I   Creating Mongo instance (driver version 2.11.4) with authority MongoAuthority{type=Direct, serverAddresses=[/127.0.0.1:27017], credentials={credentials={}}} and options MongoOptions{description='null', connectionsPerHost=100, threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier=5, maxWaitTime=120000, connectTimeout=10000, socketTimeout=0, socketKeepAlive=false, autoConnectRetry=false, maxAutoConnectRetryTime=0, slaveOk=false, readPreference=primary, dbDecoderFactory=DefaultDBDecoder.DefaultFactory, dbEncoderFactory=DefaultDBEncoder.DefaultFactory, safe=false, w=0, wtimeout=0, fsync=false, j=false, socketFactory=javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory@f6fb9709, cursorFinalizerEnabled=true, writeConcern=WriteConcern { "getlasterror" : 1} / (Continue Inserting on Errors? false), alwaysUseMBeans=false}
[08.09.14 20:09:57:060 CEST] 000001ba Mongo         I   Creating Mongo instance (driver version 2.11.4) with authority MongoAuthority{type=Direct, serverAddresses=[/127.0.0.1:27017], credentials={credentials={}}} and options MongoOptions{description='null', connectionsPerHost=100, threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier=5, maxWaitTime=120000, connectTimeout=10000, socketTimeout=0, socketKeepAlive=false, autoConnectRetry=false, maxAutoConnectRetryTime=0, slaveOk=false, readPreference=primary, dbDecoderFactory=DefaultDBDecoder.DefaultFactory, dbEncoderFactory=DefaultDBEncoder.DefaultFactory, safe=false, w=0, wtimeout=0, fsync=false, j=false, socketFactory=javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory@f6fb9709, cursorFinalizerEnabled=true, writeConcern=WriteConcern { "getlasterror" : 1} / (Continue Inserting on Errors? false), alwaysUseMBeans=false}
[08.09.14 20:09:57:070 CEST] 000000c9 mongodb       I   multiple Mongo instances for same host, jmx numbers might be off
[08.09.14 20:09:57:070 CEST] 000001ba mongodb       I   multiple Mongo instances for same host, jmx numbers might be off
[08.09.14 20:09:57:111 CEST] 000001ba SystemOut     O INFO  MongoDBConnection initializeClient - Creating mongo client for localhost:27017
[08.09.14 20:09:57:111 CEST] 000001ba Mongo         I   Creating Mongo instance (driver version 2.11.4) with authority MongoAuthority{type=Direct, serverAddresses=[localhost/127.0.0.1:27017], credentials={credentials={}}} and options MongoOptions{description='null', connectionsPerHost=100, threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier=5, maxWaitTime=120000, connectTimeout=10000, socketTimeout=0, socketKeepAlive=false, autoConnectRetry=false, maxAutoConnectRetryTime=0, slaveOk=false, readPreference=primary, dbDecoderFactory=DefaultDBDecoder.DefaultFactory, dbEncoderFactory=DefaultDBEncoder.DefaultFactory, safe=false, w=0, wtimeout=0, fsync=false, j=false, socketFactory=javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory@f6fb9709, cursorFinalizerEnabled=true, writeConcern=WriteConcern { "getlasterror" : 1} / (Continue Inserting on Errors? false), alwaysUseMBeans=false}
```

Please also note the different server addresses in the logs: serverAddresses=[localhost/127.0.0.1:27017] and serverAddresses=[/127.0.0.1:27017]. I'm setting localhost as the host name in my code.

Below you find the producer method for the mongo client.

```
@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
public MongoClient initializeClient() {
    log.info(String.format("Creating mongo client for %s:%s", host, port));
    MongoClient client = null;
    try {
        client = new MongoClient(host, port);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    return client;
}
```

Does someone know what causes these two other instances to be created and how can I prevent that?

Comment: What do you find when you search your project for `new MongoClient`?

Comment: I only find the producer method that calls `new MongoClient`. Additionally I find as expected the injection of the client in my rest gateway, as well as the disposer method in the same class as the producer method when I search for references of `MongoClient`.

Comment: I think it's the driver doing this when creating a connection pool. Check the driver documentation and source code.